# Save variables in ngFor loop, that result out of an item

Tags: angular, loops, variables, typescript, ngfor

I was curious, whats the right way to save a variable, resulting out of an item, in a `*ngFor` loop, as I don't want to call one function several times for efficiency reasons

example of what I am trying to do:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; let value = getValue(item)" [ngClass]="{'alert':!value}">
  <div *ngIf="!value">
    alert
  </div>
  {{item}}
</div>
```

example of what I am trying to avoid:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'alert':!getValue(item)}">
  <div *ngIf="!getValue(item)">
    alert
  </div>
  {{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include your `getValue` function?

Answer (score 1):

Put your `items` into a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, and return the proper value for each item.

```
function valueize(items: any[]): any[] {
    return items.map(item => {
        name: item.name,
        description: item.description,
        // etc...
    };
}

<div *ngFor="let item of valueize(items); let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'alert':!item}">
  <div *ngIf="!item">
    alert
  </div>
  {{item}}
</div>
```

You may want to do this before the `*ngFor` is even called, so you can just do `*ngFor="let item of items"` where each `item` in `items` is already the proper value. You can do that inside your constructor or `ngOnInit`, for example.

**Edit:**

As ChrisG mentioned, you can make this cleaner if you already have your `getValue` function by doing the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items.map(getValue); let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'alert':!item}">
  <div *ngIf="!item">
    alert
  </div>
  {{item}}
</div>
```

This way you don't have to create a whole new function to map, you just map inline and for each item you call the adapter function on it, thus giving each `item` the proper value.

Comment: If they already have the `getValue` function, they can inline this more simply.

`*ngFor="let item of items.map(getValue); let i = index"`

Comment: Nice and clean!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want.

Only thing you could do is to create an array, store the values in the array and then fetch them using index. Something like ...

```
let data = [];
.
.
.
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" ngClass="{'alert':!data[i]}">
{{ data[i] = getValue(item) }}
  <div *ngIf="!data[i]">
    alert
  </div>
  item
</div>
```

And still am not sure if it will work, Angular is not ment for this kind of stuff, it's a lot easier to simply parse your values before pushing them to the loop, like ...

```
<div *ngFor="let value of getItemValues(items); let i = index" [ngClass]="{'alert':!value}">
  <div *ngIf="!value">
    alert
  </div>
  {{value}}
</div>
```

Where `getItemValues()` will parse all values at once.

Comment: "There is no way to do what you want" is an invalid statement. Also, your code is not very easy to read. Doing something like `{{ data[i] = getValue(item) }}` in your template is not a very good practice, when there are better alternatives like having the data prepared before looping, and so on.

Comment: "There is no way to do what you want" is a completely valid statement in current context because data manipulation is not possible in the way he wants. Also, if you can't read, I did state that preparing data before looping is a better alternative, but there's also other alternatives, maybe not as optimal but possible.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I didn't read your text, only the code. Anyways, you should not say "There is no way to do what you want" because as I said it *is* an invalid statement. You can achieve what he wants to do by means we've already described, therefore there is a way. So, instead maybe say something like "There is no way to do what you want in an *ngFor". Your original statement is very misleading to those of us who skim. Sure, it's our own fault for skimming. But most people do not have time to waste to read entire chunks of text and would rather see a clear answer right away.